# Construct func constraint in cycle

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am using accord.math to solve system with nonlinear constraints. In this example constraint have 4 variables `, x => x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] <= 1` But what if constraints should include 50 variables. How to build `, x => x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + ...+ x[50] <= 1` in cycle?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var f = new NonlinearObjectiveFunction(4, x => 0.010 * x[0] - 0.000543 * x[1] - 0.003440 * x[2] + 0.000292 * x[3]);

        var constraints = new[]
        {
           new NonlinearConstraint(4, x => x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] <= 1),
           new NonlinearConstraint(4, x => x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] >= 1),

        };

        var cobyla = new Cobyla(f, constraints);

        bool success = cobyla.Maximize();
        double minimum = cobyla.Value;        
        double[] solution = cobyla.Solution;
        Console.WriteLine(minimum);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a sum of all values in an array, you can use LINQ's `Sum()` method, like this:

```
new NonlinearConstraint(x.Length, x => x.Sum() >= 1)
```

In general, you can replace a loop with LINQ's `Enumerable.Range`. For example, to add up `x[first]` through `x[first+count-1]`, use this expression:

```
new NonlinearConstraint(
    x.Length
,   x => Enumerable.Range(first, count).Select(i => x[i]).Sum() >= 1
)
```